# Python-What is wrong with this code?

Tags: python

I just begin learning python and I am writing this code. When I run this, the cmd said "inconsistent use of tab and space in indentation" and it pointed at line "var2". Can you help me. Thank you so much in advance.

Here is my code

```
def main():
   operation = input ("What do you want to do(+,-,*,/): ")
   if (operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '*' and operation != '/'):
       #invalid operation
       print("you must enter a valid operation")
   else: 
     var1 = int(input("enter num1: ")) 
     var2 = int(input("enter num2: "))
```

Comment: Well which word do you not understand in "inconsistent use of tab and space in indentation". It means you use tabs or spaces the wrong way that line. Better remove all spacing an re-indent.

Comment: The Tab key and the space bar are two different keys. Don't mix them.

Comment: Always increase the indent in the same way, preferably with 4 spaces.

Comment: when you declare var1 and var2 you only use 2 spaces, python use 4 spaces for indentation

Comment: thank you so much !!!!! @Denziloe. I use 4 spaces and now it works

Answer (score 1):

Although your code is indented, it has a mix of tabspace and whitespaces. Python3 throws an error on this.

Use just tabspace (tab) or spaces (spacebar).

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
   operation = input ("What do you want to do(+,-,*,/): ")
   if (operation != '+' and operation != '-' and operation != '*' and operation != '/'):
       #invalid operation
       print("you must enter a valid operation")
   else:
     var1 = int(input("enter num1: "))
     var2 = int(input("enter num2: "))
     print var1 + var2
main()
```

**Output**

```
python test.py
What do you want to do(+,-,*,/): "+"
enter num1: 1
enter num2: 2
3
```

Works fine for me.

```
python --version
Python 2.6.6
```

> Although I don't know python, it works like a charm with that
>   guesswork on calling main() and print syntax. :) I should try it out!